# On iOS 13, picking between the "display" system font and the "text" system font

Tags: fonts, ios13, uifont, system-font

I am familiar with the new Apple guidelines that the system fonts should no longer be accessed by the names and only the system API should be used. Beyond this new requirement, it seems like the SF display and text fonts have been merged into one font. The app I work on has user content where the users in the past have freely used SF Display or SF Text at any size and we are hoping to still support this behavior. This appears to no longer be possible. Some code:

```
    UIFont *fontDisplay = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    UIFont *fontText = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    NSLog(@"display font %@ and %@", fontDisplay.fontName, fontDisplay.familyName);
    NSLog(@"text font %@ and %@", fontText.fontName, fontText.familyName);
```

On ios12, we get two distinct fonts:

```
display font .SFUIText and .SF UI Text
text font .SFUIDisplay and .SF UI Display
```

On ios13, we get one font:

```
display font .SFUI-Regular and .AppleSystemUIFont
text font .SFUI-Regular and .AppleSystemUIFont
```

On ios12, we used to be able to use "UIFont fontWithSize" with either fontDisplay and fontText to get a small point version of Display or a large point version of Text to support what the authors have created. On ios 13, this is no longer possible.

Does anyone know any workarounds for this new behavior?